# How to parse and modify XHTML in Node.js (supporting HTML entities and CDATA sections)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, xhtml

I am developing a Node.js app that receives an XHTML snippet (Confluence storage format), should make some modifications to it and then send back the modified XHTML. The XHTML may contain HTML entities (such as `&ouml;`) and also CDATA sections (such as `<![CDATA[test]]>`).

The challenge that I’m running into is that with the parsers that I have tried, when I parse the snippet in HTML mode, the CDATA sections break, but when I parse it in XML mode, the HTML entities are not interpreted correctly.

Below is an example how I got this to work in the browser, but how I failed to get it to work using jsdom and cheerio. Is there any other library that I could use to achieve this, or any different way to use jsdom or cheerio?

### In the browser

In the browser, I can work with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) in XML mode. Working with the test snippet `<span>&ouml;<![CDATA[ä]]></span>`, I can wrap it in an XHTML body:

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><body><span>&ouml;<![CDATA[ä]]></span></body></html>`, 'application/xml');
doc.querySelector('body').innerHTML;   // <span>ö<![CDATA[ä]]></span>
doc.querySelector('body').textContent; // öä
```

The XML MIME type ensures that the CDATA section is interpreted correctly, while the XHTML DOCTYPE makes sure that the entities are supported.

### jsdom

To achieve the same in Node.js, I attempted to use [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). The problem is that when I parse the code in HTML mode, the CDATA section gets converted into a comment, but when I parse it in XML mode, an exception is thrown because of the HTML entity:

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
const xhtml = `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><body><span>&ouml;<![CDATA[ä]]></span></body></html>`;

new JSDOM(xhtml).window.document.body.innerHTML; // <span>ö<!--[CDATA[ä]]--></span>
new JSDOM(xhtml).window.document.body.textContent; // ö
new JSDOM(xhtml, { contentType: 'application/xml' }); // Uncaught DOMException [SyntaxError]: about:blank:1:186: undefined entity.
```

**Update:** I have [reported](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3266) the problem to jsdom.

### cheerio

My preferred method to do DOM modifications in the backend would be [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/). Using cheerio in HTML mode, the CDATA section gets converted into a comment. In XML mode, the entity is not interpreted but rather double-escaped into `&amp;ouml;`. In XML mode without decoding entities, the XHTML is preserved correctly, but the entities are not interpreted correctly, which can be seen when getting the text content.

```js
import cheerio from 'cheerio';
const xhtml = `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><body><span>&ouml;<![CDATA[ä]]></span></body></html>`;

cheerio.load(xhtml).root().find('body').html(); // <span>ö<!--[CDATA[ä]]--></span>
cheerio.load(xhtml).root().find('body').text(); // ö
cheerio.load(xhtml, { xmlMode: true }).root().find('body').html(); // <span>&amp;ouml;<![CDATA[ä]]></span>
cheerio.load(xhtml, { xmlMode: true }).root().find('body').html(); // &ouml;ä
cheerio.load(xhtml, { xmlMode: true, decodeEntities: false }).root().find('body').html(); // <span>&ouml;<![CDATA[ä]]></span>
cheerio.load(xhtml, { xmlMode: true, decodeEntities: false }).root().find('body').text(); // &ouml;ä
```

**Update:** I have [reported](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/2183) the problem to cheerio.

Comment: Did you try [xmldom](https://github.com/xmldom/xmldom)? It should provide DOMParser interface and functionality for node.js. Note that you should set [mimeType `application/xhtml+xml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

Comment: @bigless It also shows an "entity not found" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was [pointed out](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/2183#issuecomment-952419972) a workaround for the issue in cheerio:

```js
cheerio.load(xhtml, { xml: { xmlMode: false, recognizeCDATA: true, recognizeSelfClosing: true } });
```

With these options, I can successfully parse XHTML in a Node.js environment.

In addition to this solution, I noticed that using the `DOMParser` in the browser has the disadvantage that there are inconsistencies between the browsers. In particular, when using query selectors in combination with XML namespaces, I sometimes had to include the namespace in the query and sometimes not. Because of these inconsistencies, jquery also [officially doesn't support XML namespaces](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4208). To achieve consistent behaviour between the browsers and also between the frontend, frontend tests and backend, I decided to use cheerio even for parsing XHTML in the browser.